# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass while using HelloSign API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rails-models

Not sure where to begin troubleshooting. I get the error at `update_attributes`. This is an app I took over from someone, and I'm not even entirely certain of the syntax, so any help would be appreciated! I'm using [this](https://github.com/jgarber/hello_sign) gem for the HelloSign API.

```
class SignatureRequest
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :application

  field :hello_sign_id
  field :signing_url
  field :details_url

    response = HelloSign.signature_request.deliver(form: FORM_ID) do |request|
          request.title         = "#{borrower.last_name} Loan Application"
          request.subject       = "blah"
          request.message       = "blah."
        end
        update_attributes(
          hello_sign_id: response[:signature_request][:signature_request_id],
          signing_url: response[:signature_request][:signing_url],
          details_url: response[:signature_request][:details_url]
        )
        response
```

Comment: if you know what line number the error was on, that would be helpful, but it's probably that your response doesn't have a :signature_request object in it.  Can we see your form?

Comment: It's ridiculously long over 10+ pages, but according to the syntax, this is updating the 3 attributes, in the instance of `:signature_request` in `response` or is it doing something else?

Comment: it's trying to update the attributes in the SignatureRequest object using the values coming from the :signature_request hash inside the  response.

Answer (score 0):

HelloSign developer here - In the time since this question was asked we've released an official Ruby SDK. We really appreciate the developer enthusiasm that led to 3rd party libraries like the one you were trying to use (especially when we hadn't yet released official SDK's in certain languages), however now you're best bet is to use our official ones if available. They should always be the most up-to-date and more importantly we can help you when you get stuck.

Give it a try here on Github.

https://github.com/HelloFax/hellosign-ruby-sdk